# ASP.NET MVC4 Table with one column that is the primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, primary-key

I'm using:

- ASP.NET MVC4
- Visual Studio 2012
- Linq2SQL
- SQL Server 2008 R2

I've got a table *Role*:

[image: Role table]

(One column that's called *RoleName*, datatype varchar(50) and is the primary key)

When I create a strongly-typed view with as model class *Roles* (extra 's' is caused by pluralisation, no issue) and scaffold template *Edit*, the result is that I only get a hidden field and no edit/input field, as shown below:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Role</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RoleName)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

This is likely due to the only column being the primary key which MVC uses to identify the database record.

I want to be able to edit every Role's RoleName. How can I make an edit page for a table with one column that is the primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust the scaffolded HTML markup to fit what you need.  You are correct that MVC made that hidden because it is a primary key.  Unhide it.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Role</legend>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoleName)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

However, and this may just be subjective, I think having an int based primary key will go a long ways in doing things like:

1. Not having a DB exception thrown if you accidentally edit or add a role name that matches an existing role name.
2. Save space in your DB when you go to attach users to roles.  Instead of having a varchar(50) duplicated for each user/role, you will only have an int duplicated. (UserId / RoleId)
3. Quicker/better indexing on integers than varchars

Comment: Thanks, I'm going for the (added) int based primary key for better compatibility with MVC.